# AoP on Microsoft Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, compact-framework, aop

I've tried with Postsharp, but their current implementation targets 2.0, and it's getting painful to make it work. Should I roll out my own AoP implementation (I'm thinking of a very VERY basic and utilitarian implementation here)

Or there is an alternative I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may wish to take a look at [Eric Bodden's list](http://www.bodden.de/tools/aop-dot-net/) which was taken from [a very similar  stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133950/what-are-the-bestmost-popular-ways-to-do-aspect-oriented-programming-aop-in-cnet).

Answer (score -1):

oOo an "out of the box" AOP on CF? You may be a little disappointed.

The best answer is [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/download/1.5/). :D The issue here though is that the download link says this:

> "It is not stable, however. Download
>   it if you want to try the new features
>   and participate in stabilizing the
>   product."

So there might be some hidden pain if you wish to use it in production. But they do [explicitly support CF](http://www.postsharp.org/about/features/)! I haven't tried it myself yet so I cannot give a review.

Eric Bodden's list is not so hot for Compact Framework which is why this question isn't very similar to [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133950/what-are-the-bestmost-popular-ways-to-do-aspect-oriented-programming-aop-in-cnet).
I had a quick look at this before the PostSharp CTP 1.5 release and I didn't find any "out of the box" ones. All of the other frameworks (including Spring.NET, which that list omits) seem to require someone to create a port for them. I doubt a port would be very easy either considering the probable use of either Serialization, Code gen on the fly, Reflection.Emit or x86 specific calls.

So yea, PostSharp FTW I guess.